# Cannot use ArrayList of type char as method's argument

Tags: java, generics

Cannot define `ArrayList<char>` as argument of `validate`. Why it cannot be done? When trying `ArrayList<?>` it works. Why? Should `ArrayList<?>` be used instead of `ArrayList<char>`? What is the difference?

```
public boolean validate(ArrayList<char> args){ ... }
```

Error: `Syntax error on token "char", Dimensions expected after this token`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
public boolean validate(List<Character> args){ ... }
```

It has to be the wrapper type - `Character` - `List<Character>`. You can't use generics with primitive types.

Answer (score 7):

```
public boolean validate(ArrayList<Character> args){ ... }
```

When use generic in java, you cant use primitive data type, but you can use [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html), which is Object that represent primitive `char` with little overhead in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like so: `public boolean validate(ArrayList<Character> args){ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you'r dealing with a generic object, such as `ArrayList<T>`, you are required to use objects.  The difference between `char` and `Character` is that `Character` is an object, and is permitted to be used inside of a generic object.

For reference, each primitive type has their own wrapper object.  You can check that out [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class).

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper class of char in Java is Character and char should be specified as Character when adding char objects or validating char objects in an ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Character>list = new ArrayList<Character>();
```